# What method should I use to overlay pictures?

Tags: php, image-processing

**I've done my research**, but I still feel significantly uninformed. I'm looking for a library that will make an actual physical (well, digital) picture composed of other pictures layered one on top of the other. I started with Imagick, but I'm not entirely sure it creates a new image other than the one rendered to the screen.

Comment: I am not sure which is 'best' but the `gd` library will definitely do this with `imagecopy`

Comment: you want to produce a single "layered" image, or you want to keep independent images in each layer? can't do layers with png/jpg/gif, but you CAN simulate the layers in html.

Comment: what research ? did you [google](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php)?

Comment: @AD7six: Yes, I Googled. I found all the interesting ones through the PHP manual as a matter of fact. If you read the description, I was/am still confused on which ones would actually output a new image file to my server.

Comment: @MarcB: I want to produce a single "layered" image. I guess "transpose" would be the more appropriate term here. I don't care about having separate layer data after all's said and done.

Comment: @NappingRabbit : Yeah, the rest of them have a function for it as well, I guess the bigger question I should have highlighted here is "Which ones will output a new file to my server when run?"

Comment: I personally have only used `GD` for this purpose.  I do know that it WILL do so.  I dont know about others.  php.net will illustrate sufficiently for you to try it out.

Comment: @TimMetcalfe I did read the description - I didn't (and still cannot) read any of your research in the question. If you've already generated an image matching what you want to do and have output it to screen successfully, just output it to a file instead - is that what you mean? I still feel you are squarely in google territory. -1 remains since there's **no code in the question** and **no example or desired output**

Comment: @AD7six I'm not looking for reputation, so I don't care if you mark it down. I'm looking for an answer. There's no code in the question because it's not a code-specific question, it's asking where I should look in order to accomplish what I want to accomplish. The desired output is pretty straightforward, and as I've stated I have used Google, I just don't understand how to output to a file rather than a screen. I'm now looking at GD... and there it is. I've looked over this list a hundred times and I'm just now seeing imagepng which does exactly what I wanted. So hard to just say that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An actual image of the output you are after would help.

Is it something like this?

[image: Overlapped photos]

Change these lines from this

```
/* Output the image */
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
```

to this

```
/* Save the image as output.png in the same folder as the code */
$canvas->writeImage('output.jpg');  
$canvas->destroy();
```

Comment: Something much simpler. I just want to take several pictures of the same size, with transparent areas, lay them directly one over the other, and produce a new image. I've been told I can do this with almost all of the libraries, I just need one that would then produce a new file on my server with the result. @NappingRabbit's said to use GD.

Comment: The last couple of lines of your code will specify wether you are saving or displaying - what code have you used? Or what code do you want to use as GD, Imagick and Imagemagick will all do it.

Comment: I've been using Imagick thusfar, with an obvious lack of comprehension. I followed [the example on the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php), twisted it a bit to suit my needs, but I only understood enough to get it to output the resulting image to a screen, as detailed in the tutorial.

So, to say it plainly, I used `header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;` where `$canvas` is the resulting image.

Comment: See addition to my answer above.

Comment: Sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar. If I had enough rep, I'd upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) will do the trick - just render transparent PNG in order to get your layers, then place them one above the other via CSS:

```
.layers img{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**Markup:**

```
<div class="layers">
  <img src="someScript.php">
  <img src="someScript.php">
  <img src="someScript.php">
</img>
```

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't have said "layers". By layers I meant transposing one image onto another, not having particular layer data. The bigger question I should have highlighted is "Which method(s) actually produce a new image file from the result?"

Comment: You can still do this with GD. Eg. call your source images, scale/flip/rotate (repeat) and output in a format of choice.

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm looking at GD rather than Imagick, everything's a bit clearer. Many thanks to you and everybody else saying look at GD, it's actually answering my question!